# Numba `cache=True ` has no effect

Tags: python, numba

I write below code to test cache feature of numba

```
import numba
import numpy as np
import time
@numba.njit(cache=True)
def sum2d(arr):
    M, N = arr.shape
    result = 0.0
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            result += arr[i,j]
    return result
a=np.random.random((1000,100))
print(time.time())
sum2d(a)
print(time.time())
print(time.time())
sum2d(a)
print(time.time())
```

Though, there are some cache files generated in **pycache** folder, the timing is always the same like

```
1576855294.8787484
1576855295.5378428
1576855295.5378428
1576855295.5388253
```

no matter how many times I run this script, which means that first run of `sum2d` takes much more time to compile. Then what is usage of cache file in **pycache** folder?

Answer (score 10):

The following script illustrates the point of `cache=True`. It first calls a non-cached `dummy` function that absorbs the time it takes to initialize `numba`. Then it proceeds with calling twice the `sum2d` function with no cache and twice the `sum2d` function with cache.

```
import numba
import numpy as np
import time

@numba.njit
def dummy():
    return None

@numba.njit
def sum2d_nocache(arr):
    M, N = arr.shape
    result = 0.0
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            result += arr[i,j]
    return result

@numba.njit(cache=True)
def sum2d_cache(arr):
    M, N = arr.shape
    result = 0.0
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            result += arr[i,j]
    return result

start = time.time()
dummy()
end = time.time()
print(f'Dummy timing {end - start}')

a=np.random.random((1000,100))
start = time.time()
sum2d_nocache(a)
end = time.time()
print(f'No cache 1st timing {end - start}')

a=np.random.random((1000,100))
start = time.time()
sum2d_nocache(a)
end = time.time()
print(f'No cache 2nd timing {end - start}')

a=np.random.random((1000,100))
start = time.time()
sum2d_cache(a)
end = time.time()
print(f'Cache 1st timing {end - start}')

a=np.random.random((1000,100))
start = time.time()
sum2d_cache(a)
end = time.time()
print(f'Cache 2nd timing {end - start}')
```

Output after 1st run:

```
    Dummy timing 0.10361385345458984
    No cache 1st timing 0.08893513679504395
    No cache 2nd timing 0.00020122528076171875
    Cache 1st timing 0.08929300308227539
    Cache 2nd timing 0.00015544891357421875
```

Output after 2nd run:

```
    Dummy timing 0.08973526954650879
    No cache 1st timing 0.0809786319732666
    No cache 2nd timing 0.0001163482666015625
    Cache 1st timing 0.0016787052154541016
    Cache 2nd timing 0.0001163482666015625
```

What does this output tells us?

- The time to initialize `numba` is not negligible.
- During the first run, the first call of the cache and non-cache version take longer due to compilation time.
- In this example, the creation of the cache file doesn't make much of a difference.
- In the second run, the first call to the cache function is much faster (this is what `cache=True` is for)
- The subsequent calls to the cache and non-cache functions take approximately the same time.

The point of using `cache=True` is to avoid repeating the compile time of large and complex functions at each run of a script. In this example the function is simple and the time saving is limited but for a script with a number of more complex functions, using cache can significantly reduce the run-time.

Comment: You are not measuring the caching feature (you will get the same timings with or without `cache=True`) To do this you can eg. create a `sum2d(arr)_0` without caching and a second `sum2d(arr)_1` with caching. Take the timings on the first call -> restart Interpreter -> take the timings on the second call. The first call to another non cached function is just to exclude the constant time for importing and initializing Numba.

Comment: @max9111 Sure, sorry I missed this, will update the answer.

Comment: @max9111 I've updated the answer. Let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks for putting me back in the right direction!

Comment: +1 With dummy function I meant any other function before taking the time. sum2d_nocache(arr) should be enough. One thing could be additionally mentioned: This function is very simple, there are a lot more complicated functions possible including parallelization, which easily takes >2s to compile. The effect of caching should be more obvious there.