# Faster way to find the next greatest value in array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to improve the runtime of my dataframe code. Is my line of thought wrong?

I have the following code to find the first value in column 1 that is higher than `value` and has a higher index than it (`index_value=n`)

```
new_index=(df[n:,1] > value).argmax()
```

My question is: the argmax() argument will build a complete list with Trues and Falses then, and only then, it will find the first occurence and return my expected index.

Is there a way to improve on this code? i.e stop constructing a list after the first `True` is found.

Comment: Use numba and `break` out after the first occurence?

Comment: Can you explain to me how would I do that?

Comment: You just loop through the input array for the greater than comparison and you break out after the first occurence. Nothing too complicated there.

Comment: kindly share a data to make ur question clearer, plus expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wasn't planning to make any post. I was expecting numba to win in all conditions, but that wasn't meant to be. Ran few benchmarks on the proposed solutions and the results were somewhat interesting, hence posting here. I am going with array data to keep things simple.

```
# Proposed solutions
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

# @piRSquared's soln
@njit
def find_first_gt(a, n, value):
    while a[n] <= value:
        n += 1
    return n

# @Ehsan's soln
def numpy_argmax(a, n , value):
    return np.argmax(a[n:] > value)
```

Using [`benchit`](https://github.com/droyed/benchit) package (few benchmarking tools packaged together; disclaimer: I am its author) to benchmark proposed solutions.

Timings and speedups -

```
# Benchmark
a = np.arange(1000_000)
n = 0

import benchit
funcs = [find_first_gt, numpy_argmax]
vs = np.linspace(0, len(a)-1, num=20, endpoint=True).astype(int)
inputs = [(a,0,v) for v in vs]
t = benchit.timings(funcs, inputs, multivar=True, input_name='Position of value')
t.plot(logy=False, logx=False, savepath='plot.png')
t.speedups(ref_func_by_index=1).plot('Speedup_with_numba.png')
```

[image]

[image]

If you are interested in the exact speedup numbers -

```
In [12]: t.speedups(ref_func_by_index=1)
Out[12]: 
Functions          find_first_gt  Ref:numpy_argmax
Position of value                                 
0                    2103.548010               1.0
52631                  22.053699               1.0
105263                 11.109615               1.0
157894                  7.541725               1.0
210526                  5.640514               1.0
263157                  4.407300               1.0
315789                  3.642989               1.0
368420                  3.028726               1.0
421052                  2.543713               1.0
473683                  2.201336               1.0
526315                  1.931540               1.0
578946                  1.692138               1.0
631578                  1.536912               1.0
684209                  1.455065               1.0
736841                  1.357728               1.0
789472                  1.248716               1.0
842104                  1.176199               1.0
894735                  1.062174               1.0
947367                  1.043791               1.0
999999                  0.983419               1.0
```

Conclusion : In almost all conditions, `numba` does a good job, unless you know the `value` is at the very far end or the numba-caching schemes are off-putting for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you convert the data frame to numpy:

Use `np.argmax(df[n:,1] > value)`. It stops at the first value. It is significantly faster than `(df[n:,1] > value).argmax()` when the first occurrence is much closer to n compared to size of search array. However as the first occurrence gets closer to the end of array, both methods have to go through most part of array.

To convert a column by index number to numpy array:

```
np.argmax(df.iloc[:, 1].to_numpy()[n:] > value)
```

UPDATE: compare time:
Finding element `999,998` in `np.arange(1,000,000)`

```
np.argmax(df[n:,1] > value)    time = 0.0008049319999998694
(df[n:,1] > value).argmax()    time = 0.0013422100000000103
Using numba while loop         time = 0.14520884199999995
```

EDIT: Please checkout [@piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61273910/4975981) for time comparison as well. The performances of numpy v. numba seem to be comparable in that answer. I am not sure why it is different under two settings.

Comment: I'm guessing you're doing something wrong.  I tested this and my results are very different.  Yes, I could wrong as well.  But I'd ask you to look at what I tested and see what you think.

Comment: Thank you. This is interesting and could be a question by itself. I copied your code and used numba.  I am not sure of implementations of numba under different systems. Any idea of why it comes so different?

Comment: @Ehsan Well with numba, it does caching during the first runs. So, I think a widely used benchmarking practice is to record the timings after few runs.

Comment: For the record, I'd use numpy.  Numba is a tool that can be finicky and I only use it when I really need the performance.  I don't believe the benefit justifies the added complexity in this case.

Comment: Added benchmark numbers and plots in a community wiki post here.

Comment: @Ehsan You are very likely measuring the very first call (you are actually measuring compilation and runtime). If you have many Numba functions and more complex ones make use of caching eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61209673/4045774

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, and borrowing [@Divakar's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61273681/faster-way-to-find-the-next-greatest-value-in-array#comment108396707_61273681)

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def find_first_gt(a, n, value):
    while a[n] <= value:
        n += 1
    return n

find_first_gt(df[1].to_numpy(), n, value)
```

---

Under a naive test we find that the while loop is on the order of twice as slow as numpy.

```
a = np.arange(1_000_000)
n = 0
value = 999_998

%timeit np.argmax(a > value)
%timeit find_first_gt(a, n, value)

322 µs ± 1.52 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
620 µs ± 66.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

However, this test explicitly tests when the index is the penultimate position.  On average, the index will be in the middle.  So lets test over all values in the array.

```
def test_numpy(a, n):
    for value in a[::1000]:
        np.argmax(a > value)

def test_find_first(a, n):
    for value in a[::1000]:
        find_first_gt(a, n, value)

a = np.arange(1_000_000)
n = 0

%timeit test_numpy(a, n)
%timeit test_find_first(a, n)

300 ms ± 1.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
276 ms ± 1.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

In which we find that the average results are roughly the same.

Comment: This is extremely slower than either `df.argmax()` and `np.argmax()`

Comment: I show this as the opposite.  The function I provided is faster.  Can you provide objective evidence of your claim?  Keep in mind that I use `numba`.  If you're not using `numba` to test then the test isn't valid.

Comment: I ran your code alongside the other two methods on the same values and put the runtime in my post.

Comment: Added benchmark numbers and plots in a community wiki post here.